# How to grep a group of files within a time range?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to write a script used on a buffer box that does full packet capture of network traffic. As it's for a fairly big network we split the captures into 100MB segments. At times of high network traffic oftentimes over a one minute period we will have multiple pcaps which cover that period.

So what I want to do is have a bash script that lets the analyst who is searching for something specify a date and time and how many minutes either side of it they want to search for files. Obviously I can do something like this -

```
ls -al | grep "Dec  1" | grep 02:00
ls -al | grep "Dec  1" | grep 02:01
```

and so on, get each result and grep each file individually for the specific keyword I'm looking for, but I'd like to be able to do a wider search for all files created within a time range and then grep each of them for the keyword.

I'm not entirely sure how to do that, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `find` command is your friend, especially the `-ctime`, `-mtime` and/or `-newer` options.  Do a `man find` for more details.

Comment: Yeah I've looked into using find, but that only works in days. We have 100% capture on the network for 30 days, averaging maybe, I dunno... thousands of 100mb segments per day. Doing searches over days of packets will put unnecessary strain on an already heavily loaded system.

Comment: Culled from `man find`:

 -ctime n[smhdw]
             s       second
             m       minute (60 seconds)
             h       hour (60 minutes)
             d       day (24 hours)
             w       week (7 days) 

So you can specify units

Comment: I need to look for files in a RANGE of times on a specific date. Say between 11:20pm and 11:30pm on 3rd November.

Comment: Here is a method using find: http://aaronbonner.io/post/28969404367/find-and-delete-files-between-two-dates (just omit the delete portion of course).

Comment: I would use `stat` and `date` to find the files

Comment: If your version of `find` supports the `-newer` test with a filename parameter, use `touch` to create files whose modification date/times are at the beginning and end of your desired range, and then use the expression `-newer file2 ! –newer file1`.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the fine things `find` (on GNU/Linux) can do for you:

Units:

- `n` exactly *n* untis
- `-n` less than *n* units
- `+n` more than *n* units  -

What happened:

- `-atime`: last time **accessed**
- `-ctime`: changes on **file itself** (permissions, owners, …), not its content
- `-mtime`: **file's content** changed
- `-amin n`: *n* minutes age
- `-atime n`: *n* days (24 hours) ago
- same goes for `ctime/min` and `mtime/min`)

Thus:

- `find -atime -30` → last accessed less than 30 days ago
- `find -ctime +5` → more than 5 days ago, changes on file itself
- `find -mtime +2 -31` → file's content changed more than two days but less than 31 days ago

also
 - `-daystart`: after today, 0.00h

---

Grepping

`find` *stuff* **`-exec grep {} \;`** →; the last part (`{} \;`) is essential - mind the single white space between `{}` and `\;`

The `-exec` options allows incorporating other commands into `find`

---

Also: [Why one shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1):

find  -iname "" -mtime -7 -exec zgrep "" {} \;

For ex-

find /opt/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/application/logs/ -iname "SystemOut*" -mtime -7 -exec zgrep "FileNotFoundException" {} \;

It will find within directory /opt/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/application/logs/ for files starting with SystemOut in last 7 days and will look for String FileNotFoundException.